# Server timestamp

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone

Refer to the picture below. I created a post. Notice the time stamp is behind by two hours The minutes and seconds are correct. To verify see my server connection is okay and my windows clock in the bottom-right is also okay. The windows clock and server clock match. As for my wall of post the hour is not correct. Why is it so?

[image: See image]

Comment: The server isn't on the same timezone with your local machine.

Comment: okay, so I must update to my timezone. thanks.

Comment: @Thabang - Please read [the TZ/DST best practices article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), as well as [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  Also, in the future, please be sure to post some code.  Screenshots are good if they supplement your question, but you should be able to demonstrate how to reproduce the problem in code first.  Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use the laravel framework, it's very likely the datetime values stored in the database are stored in UTC format. When you output the datetime values you should adjust the timezone to the timezone of the user.

http://www.camroncade.com/managing-timezones-with-laravel/

Comment: This is a decent reference article, however link-only answers are discouraged here.  Please read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I pointed him to the problem but I don't know for sure if that's the solution. I wrote what he had to do `adjust the timezone to the timezone of the user`. The link is just for extra help, so he doesn't has to write a second question on `how to handle timezones with laravel`, in case he doesn't know how to to it. I certenly don't know if he knows. One solution would be to remove the link and write a comment with the link, but i thought this would be easier to read.